# NLog list property values on Logger

Tags: c#, nlog

There is a `Logger.SetProperty(string propertyKey, object propertyValue)` method. Is there a way to list the properties that have been set on a logger object or see the value of a particular property?

Comment: NLog 4.6.4 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.6.4 (Logger now has a Properties-collection you can inspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

This has been added to NLog 4.6.4.

```
logger.Properties
```

---

**Original answer**

Unfortunately this isn't possible now (NLog 4.6.3)

I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3422) and a [pull request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3424)